# Three state checkbox with angular 2

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, checkbox

I want to do an input box with three states: checked, unchecked and crossed(a.k.a failed)
Currently, I was able to do check/uncheck and change calculations accordingly

```html
 <input type="checkbox" [ngStyle]="{content: expression}" *ngIf="milestone?.description" [checked]="milestone?.status == 'checked'" (change)="checkMilestone(milestone,initiative, $event, '')">
```

However, I have trouble adding `crossed` (`X`) checkbox. Does anyone have idea how it should be done? Should I have states something like this:

```
states = [
    { id: 0, status: 'checked'},
    { id: 1, status: 'unchecked'},
    { id: 2, status: 'crossed'}
];
```

and add styles and change them accordingly? I'm not sure how to add three styles instead of two.

Comment: See this post: [Indeterminate checkboxes](https://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/)

Comment: @Silvermind - Are you going to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @ConnorsFan If I knew how to do it with something that has compatibillity with ngModel and/or formControl I would. However, it is not as trivial as it sounds. That's why I commented an example blog with plain javascript, because it doesn't suffice as an answer imo.

Comment: I suggest instead of using a checkbox type input, you should make your on component with your logic behind the three states you need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [indeterminate](https://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/) state of the checkbox can be set with [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-). Here is a simplified version of your markup, showing the `indeterminate` state binding:

```
<input type="checkbox" [indeterminate]="milestone?.status === 'crossed'" 
  [ngModel]="milestone?.status === 'checked'" (ngModelChange)="checkMilestone(milestone)">
```

The `checkMilestone` method could be something like this:

```
checkMilestone(milestone) {
  switch (milestone.status) {
    case "checked": {
      milestone.status = "unchecked";
      break;
    }
    case "unchecked": {
      milestone.status = "crossed";
      break;
    }
    case "crossed": {
      milestone.status = "checked";
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cpzdvj) for a demo.

Comment: Excellent man thank you. I know there's something to do this, but i did'nt know its called`[indeterminate]`